# Decrease Paramiko maximal request size

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, azure-runbook

I have a Python Runbook and I would like to set the `MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024` instead of `32768` (default value) in the Paramiko's `sftp_file.py`.

Have you any idea about how can we do it??

I'am trying to transfer files from SFTP to local. And for some reasons, the transfer of files with more than 30MB is suspended automatically when achieving the 27-28 MB without getting any error message. When I changed locally the `max_request_size` to `1024`, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try slowing down the transfer instead. A very trivial implementation of transfer throttling can be like:

```
import time
```

```
bytes_per_second = 512*1024
start_time = time.time()

def callback(transferred, total):
    while (transferred / (time.time() - start_time)) > bytes_per_second:
        time.sleep(0.1)

sftp.get(filepath, os.path.join(localFilePath, entry.filename), callback)
```

---

Alternatively, just control the request size by re-implementing the download:

```
with sftp.open(filepath, "rb") as fr, \
     open(os.path.join(localFilePath, entry.filename), "wb") as fl:
    while True:
        data = fr.read(1024)
        fl.write(data)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
```

The above is a stripped down version of what [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) does internally.