# Bandwidth throttling using Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I’m using Paramiko and Python to upload files to my SFTP server. Is there a way to implement bandwidth throttling if my file is huge?

```
def upload_files(local, server):
   transport = paramiko.transport(host, port)
   transport.connect(user, password)
   sftp = Paramiko.SFTPClient.from transport(transport)
   sftp.put(local, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `callback` argument of [`SFTPClient.put`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) to implement the throttling.

Here is a sample code for download. For upload it will be pretty much the same:
[Decrease Paramiko maximal request size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62143431/850848)